# Laravel, is it possible to view all names in comma delimited using laravel relationship?

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 tables, `furnitures` and `suppliers`. In `suppliers` table have `furniture_id` field which is varchar because i'm storing its data in comma delimited data structure.

[image]

**Supplier Model**

```
public function get_furniture_name()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Furniture', 'furniture_id', 'id')
}
```

**Controller**

```
$supplier = Supplier::with('get_furniture_name')->all();
```

**View**

```
@foreach($supplier as $value)
    {{ $value->get_furniture_name->name }}
@endforeach
```

Base on code above, is it possible the first row of supplier display as `chair, desk`?

**Edit (for @Nabil Farhan answer)**

Pivoting table means I have to do like this?

[image]

and then resulting like this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It is **possible**. But what you have is a bad practice. What you should do is to make a pivot table of furniture and supplier.

Anyway, if you still don't want to change the database structure then you can do it in following way.

**Supplier Model**

```
public function get_furniture_name()
{
   $furniture_array = explode(",",$this->furniture_id);
   $str = "";
   foreach($furniture_array as $furniture_id)
   {
      $furniture = App\Furniture::find($furniture_id); //If your model name is different then use that.
      $str = $str.$furniture->name.",";
   }
   return $str;
}
```

**View**

```
@foreach($supplier as $value)
    {{ $value->get_furniture_name() }}
@endforeach
```

What this code will do is make an array from the string. Then will get the name for every elements. Then append it and return.

P.S. In your database image it is written `furnitture_id`(with double T). I assumed it is a typo and wrote the code accordingly.

**UPDATE**:
If you use pivot table then you won't need to use `pivot_id` column.

Your database structure should be like this,

```
furnitures: id, name
suppliers: id, name
furniture_supplier: furniture_id, supplier_id
```

In laravel the convention of pivot table is by combining the name of related model in alphabetical order. For your case it is 'furniture_supplier'. But if you wish you can change it.

Also, you will need to change in model for implementing [many to many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship.

Comment: I strongly agree with Nabil Farhan, @LearnProgramming. You should consider modify your DB structure to manage a many-to-many relationship in this case. That will suit your use case a lot better.

Comment: i experienced this before, afraid of using pivot table as i am accustomed to a comma delimited list on my db. we have all the help we can need online. you'll surely find the solution regarding pivot table just in case you'll run into a problem. now i'm comfortable using it. smile here.

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer, I used your method and it works great. Now im trying what you guys suggested by pivoting tables. Base on the edited question, is it correct?